# Are vampires really immune to garlic or was that a bluff?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lost-boys

During the final confrontation in *The Lost Boys* one of the vampires says that garlic is not affecting them and they even used a holy water/garlic mix to beat them up and we never got a confirmation about it in the film and I partially (not surely) remember garlic being used in *Lost Boys: The Tribe*.

So was that vampire just bluffing or does garlic have no effect on vampires?

Answer (score 5):

I have to spoiler pretty much all of this since it gives away a major twist in the movie.

When Max eats dinner with the Emersons, Sam and Edgar test him using garlic and  holy water, among other things. Unfortunately, Max took the precaution of getting Michael to invite him in. Later in the movie, when Max is revealed to be the head vampire, he says, "Don't ever invite a vampire into your house, you silly boy. It renders you powerless," implying that the invitation was what allowed him to pass the tests.

Later though, Paul says, "Haha! Garlic don't work, boys!" which implies that garlic wouldn't work regardless, and since they used a garlic and holy water mix to kill him, we can't be sure whether the garlic had any effect or it was simply the holy water that did him in.

Comment: Didn't answered my question and there is no need for that much spoiler markup

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I neither want to spoil the film's one big twist nor a punchline near the film's climax, and this question can't be answered without touching on those scenes. Anyway, I think this is as close to an answer as you'll get from the original film.

Comment: The question is *already about the film*. Any answer is *expected* to spoil at least this very film.